# How to stub a method with argument in MiniTest

Tags: ruby, minitest

I can `stub` a method like this:

```
def test_stale_eh
  obj_under_test = Something.new
  refute obj_under_test.stale?

  Time.stub :now, Time.at(0) do
    assert obj_under_test.stale?
  end
end
```

from http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/minitest/4.2.0/Object:stub

But I couldn't find information how to stub a method with arguments.
For example if I want to stub a `Time.parse` method, how can I write it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want the result to be always the same (i.e. the result of the stubbed method doesn’t depend on the argument), you can just pass it as the value to `stub`:

```
expected_time = Time.at(2)

Time.stub :parse, Time.at(2) do
  assert_equal expected_time, Time.parse("Some date")
end
```

If you want to return a different result depending on the argument, you can pass something callable. [The docs say](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/minitest/4.2.0/Object:stub):

> If `val_or_callable responds` to #call, then it returns the result of calling it, otherwise returns the value as-is.

This means you can do something like this contrived example:

```
stub = Proc.new do |arg|
  arg == "Once upon a time" ? Time.at(0) : Time.new(2016, 9, 30)
end

Time.stub :parse, stub do
  assert_equal Time.new(2016, 9, 30), Time.parse("A long, long time ago")
  assert_equal Time.at(0), Time.parse("Once upon a time")
end
```

Comment: The best answer on the entire internet!